# Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string: ' '

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpstorm

Sorry I am pretty new to Linux machine and Ubuntu.

**Here is what I did:**

1. I tried to install PhpStorm 2016.3.2 on Linux machine (Ubuntu) by downloading the .gz file from JetBrains site.
2. I extracted the `PhpStorm-2016.3.2.tar.gz` file inside `/home/[USERNAME]/apps/phpstorm/` folder.
3. I went inside `bin/` folder and typed command line  `./phpstorm.sh` using Terminal.
4. It opens the PhpStorm application, but..

**Error message:**

It shows `Error parsing gtk-icon-sizes string:  ' '` message while opening the app.

**Problem:**

1. Application cannot stay open unless this Terminal stays open.
2. PhpStorm's icon is not created on my machine, so every time if I want to open PhpStorm, I have to open Terminal and type `./phpstorm.sh`.

**Question:**

While I was looking for solution, I got a feedback that I need to edit `.bashrc` file to make it executable in that path. What does it mean?
Do I have to modify the path inside "jediterm-bash.in"–> function load_interactive_configs?

[image: Error message in Terminal]

[image: Bashrc path?]

Comment: It's more of a Linux/Ubuntu issue -- try asking here: http://askubuntu.com/